# Two planes questions angles and parametric equations?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Consider the two planes $P_1 : x + y − z = 2$ and $P_2 : 3x − 4y + 5z = 6$. 
> (a) Find the parametric equations of their line of intersection.
> (b) Find the angle between the two planes.

I am not seeking an answer as much as I am checking my solution. Any feedback is much appreciated

a)
To find the parametric equations in part (a), I found a point of intersection on the two planes by setting $z = 0$. I solved the equations to obtain the point $(2,0,0)$. To obtain the other $t$ vectors I add the point vector $\langle2,0,0\rangle$ to the cross product of the normal vectors $n_1\times n_2 =
\langle -15, -8, -7\rangle$.

Parameterization of the line of intersection:

$$r(t) = \langle 2, 0, 0\rangle + t\langle -15, -8, -7\rangle$$

Final answer:

$$r(t) = \langle 2-15t, -8t, -7t\rangle$$

Please let me know if I was right or I need to modify. Thank you.

b) I know part two is just the angle between the two normal vectors.

Comment: When I solve your system of equations, I get $\langle 2,0,0 \rangle + t\langle \frac{-1}{7}, \frac{8}{7}, 1 \rangle$. Maybe I did something wrong (which would make sense, because I'm a beginner in this area).

Comment: Hmm... when I graph it on GeoGebra it seems to work out...

Comment: I might have made a numerical calculation error.I am more interested in the method rather than the final answer. I am simulating this for an exam. I am only giving myself a few minutes to do this without a calculator. This is going to be on my midterm in about a week. You are probably right.

Comment: I just created an augmented matrix from your values and used Gaussian elimination to solve the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were right. The line you have is a translation of the line through origin perpendicular to both normals (and hence parallel to both planes), by a point on the intersection.

Comment: Thanks, I just am practicing.